# Visual Studio throws error on file I removed from the project

Tags: c++, visual-studio

As the title says, I've removed a file from a project I'm working on but it still shows up in the build (well, the errors that is).

I have no idea why it would do that. I cleaned the project and did a full rebuild. I checked everything in the Solution Explorer but can't find the file.

Comment: is your file a header file and you still include it somewhere? If so, remove the includes to that file

Comment: have you tried deleting the physical file from the folder location using windows explorer?

Comment: Thanks Flocke! I somehow forgot to check that and that was it :) thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Removing the files from the project directory is not enough you need to remove the actual file from the file system to avoid ambiguity so navigate using the windows explorer and delete the file.